# How to reorder sub components in Altium Designer

Tags: altium

Is there a simple way to reorder sub components in a SCHlib?

I have a part with multiple sub parts and I want to reorder them into a logical order?

[image]

For smaller parts I've just resorted to copying and pasting the contents of each subpart into the part I want but for large parts this is getting unbearable.

For example I want to swap Part M with Part P. You'd have though this would be as simple as dragging them into the order of your choice but alas not!

Comment: are the parts sorted by name? ... what happens if you rename them?